# A and B be two events of the same probability space. Equivalent

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this probation calculation demo exercise and I do not know very well

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events of the same probability space. They are equivalent

$A$ and $B$ are independent

$A$ and $B^\complement$ are independent

$A^\complement$ and $B$ are independent

$A^\complement$ and $B^\complement$ are independent

((being c complemented))

Apart from the question I do not understand very wellI have managed to show that $A^\complement$ and $B^\complement$ are independent if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent, but for this new exercise I can not use any of this obtained. Can someone give me a hand how to continue? Is there a rule or something that you do not know that can be applied to prove it?

Comment: "I have managed to show that A and B are independent if and only if A and B are independent" ... can you clarify this?

Comment: @grand_chat Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let it be that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Then:$$P(A\cap B^{\complement})=P(A)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)(1-P(B))=P(A)P(B^{\complement})$$

showing that also $A$ and $B^{\complement}$ are independent.

Applying this principle it can be shown that the $4$ statements in your question are equivalent.

That's what this is about.

Comment: So I have to show that for the four possibilities, which are independent and in all are equivalent because they give the same? I do not understand very well the reasoning that you have put

Comment: You exposed $4$ statements in your question. I suspect you are asked to prove that these $4$ statements are equivalent. If you number the statements by $1,2,3,4$ then in my answer you find a proof of $1\implies 2$. This can easily be extended. The end result must be: $1\iff2\iff3\iff4$.